# Using strtok to tokenize html

Tags: c, text-parsing

I'm looking to extract text found exactly within an `<` and `>`, while also extracting things found between `>` and `<`.

For instance:

- `<html>` would just return `<html>`
- `<title>This is a title</title>` would return `<title>`, `This is a title`, `</title>`
- `This is a title` would return `This is a title`
- And finally `<title>This is a weird use of < bracket</title>` should return `<title>`, `This is a weird use of < bracket`, `</title>`. My current version recognises it as `<title>`, `This is a weird use of`, `< bracket`, `</title>`

I'd appreciate any snippets of code, or directions to head in to get to a solution.

tldr, grab substrings with `<...>` and `>...<` seperately without being stumped by a floating `...>...` or `...<...`.

Edit: not using `strtok` anymore, would appreciate any other help or similiar problems you may know about. Any thing to read also would be greatly beneficial. Note: we aren't trying to parse, simply lex the input string

Can only use standard libraries for c.

Comment: `strtok` is not your friend. You should parse the HTML syntax explicitly with loops and tests.

Comment: Oh yah, `strtok` is totally the wrong approach here because HTML is way too complicated to parse this way (and regular expressions aren't right either). Best to look around for a C library that can do this for you; you probably want a SAX parser that gives you tokens one a time rather than a DOM parser that builds a whole HTML tree in memory (unless that's what you're looking for).

Comment: Just trying to build a basic validator for a subset of valid HTML.  I'm limited to standard C libraries.

Answer (score 1):

> Just trying to build a basic validator for a subset of valid HTML.

You can't, not even a basic one. You will have too many false positives and negatives. Here's a simple example.

```
<tag attribute=">" />
```

HTML has many features which do not allow simple parsing. It is...

- Balanced, like `<tag></tag>` and also `"quotes"`.
- Nested, like `<tag><tag></tag></tag>`.
- Escaped, like `"escaped\"quote"`.
- Has other languages embedded in it, like Javascript and CSS.

If this is an exercise in tokenization, you could define a very specific subset, but I'd suggest something simpler like [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) which has a [well defined grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar). Those are typically parsed using a [lexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) and [parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler-compiler), but JSON is small enough to be written by hand.

Comment: This is the correct approach. One could get a lexer that [compiles to a C programme](https://re2c.org/), much simpler and less error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

My own solution has been thus so far,

as suggested by @chqrlie...

```c
void tokenize(char* stringPtr)
{
    char *flag;
    strcpy(flag, " ");
    /*We build this up as we iterate the string.
    Strtok was not suitable, build up tokens char by char */
    char tempToken[tokenLength];
    strcpy(tempToken, ""); // Init current token

    // Traverse string catching stuff between <...> and >...< seperately.
    for(int i =0; i<strlen(stringPtr);i++)
    {
        if (stringPtr[i]=='<' )
        {
            if (strcmp(flag, " ")==0)
            {
                putToken(tempToken);
                strcpy(tempToken,"");  // Tag starting, everything before it is a token. 
                strcpy(flag,"<");
                strcat(tempToken, flag);
            }
            else // Catches <...< 
            {
                presentError(stringPtr);
            }
        }
        else if (stringPtr[i]=='>')
        {
            if (strcmp(flag,"<")==0)
            {
                strcat(tempToken, ">");
                strcpy(flag," ");
                putToken(tempToken);
                strcpy(tempToken,"");
            }
            else // Cant have a > unless we saw < already
            {
                presentError(stringPtr);
            }
        }
        else // Manage non angle brackets
        {
            strncat(tempToken, &stringPtr[i],1 );
        }
    }
    putToken(tempToken); // Catches a line ending in a value, not a tag

    /* Notes 
    Floating <'s and >'s will be errored up
        - Special case ....<...>..., which is incorrect 
          will cause floating tokens, can be identified
    Unclosed tags i.e. </p will be tokenized verbatim, 
    thus can identify this mistake
    Unopened tags i.e. p> will be errored
    */
}
```

Assume that `presentError()` terminates lexing.

Some improvements can be made, I'm open to suggestions however *this is a first working draft*.

Comment: You failed to allocate any memory for `stack`. `stack` is never allocated and should not be freed, and it should be allocated on the stack. `strcpy` and `strcat` are dangerous as they have no checks to ensure you're not going past your allocated memory.

Comment: @Schwern, Thanks for the feedback. An assumption was made that all strings passed into the tokenizer have length <= 255, thus strcat and strcpy will never exceed the allocated memory. 

I'll ensure stack has the correct memory allocation. It's just a single character.

Comment: `stack` doesn't have enough memory, `" "` is two bytes, one for the space and one for the terminating null. malloc is only necessary if the memory needs to live beyond the function, allocate it using automatic memory: `char stack[] = ""`. If you're only storing a single character, use just a single character: `char stack = '\0'`. Finally, `stack` isn't a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)). You're using it like a boolean to track if you're inside a tag. `bool in_tag = false`. You're struggling with basics, I again encourage you to consider JSON; it's simpler.

Comment: @Schwern noted :) admittedly calling it stack wasn't the best thing to do.